# Create a single search box which searches two different sites using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search-box

I've made multiple search boxes that search external dictionary sites. Due to the site search syntax, I've had to use JavaScript to construct a url from the text box input. This code works perfectly fine:

```js
function prepare_link_glosbe() {
      var url_param_gl = document.getElementById('url_param_gl');
      var target_link_gl = document.getElementById('target_link_gl');

      if ( ! url_param_gl.value ) {
           return false;  
      }

      target_link_gl.href = "https://nb.glosbe.com/en/nb"
      target_link_gl.href = target_link_gl.href + '/' + encodeURI(url_param_gl.value);
      window.open(target_link_gl.href, '_blank')
 }
 function prepare_link_dict() {
      var url_param_dict = document.getElementById('url_param_dict');
      var target_link_dict = document.getElementById('target_link_dict');

      if ( ! url_param_dict.value ) {
           return false;  
      }

      target_link_dict.href = "https://www.dict.com/engelsk-norsk"
      target_link_dict.href = target_link_dict.href + '/' + encodeURI(url_param_dict.value);
      window.open(target_link_dict.href, '_blank')
 }
```

```html
<!--Search Glosbe.com-->
<div style="border:0px solid black;padding:8px;width:60em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Search glosbe.com" name="url_param_gl" id="url_param_gl" size="40"/>
<input type="button" onclick="prepare_link_glosbe()" value="Glosbe (en-no)" />
<a href="https://nb.glosbe.com/en/nb" id="target_link_gl" target="_blank" ></a>
</td></tr></table></div>

<!--Search Dict.com-->
<div style="border:0px solid black;padding:8px;width:60em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Search dict.com" name="url_param_dict" id="url_param_dict" size="40"/>
<input type="button" onclick="prepare_link_dict()" value="Dict (en-no)" />
<a href="https://www.dict.com/engelsk-norsk" id="target_link_dict" target="_blank" ></a>
</td></tr></table></div>
```

However, I wish to search both sites using a single input box. I've tried different approaches, including addEventListener, but I'm not fluent enough in either HTML or JavaScript to achieve it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some things that will make your life easier in the long run:

1. You don't need `this.value=''`, just use the `placeholder` attribute - it's well supported.
2. Don't use `<table>` to create a layout.
3. Don't use attributes to assign JS event handlers. (so no `onclick=`)

And now, how to use just one text field for both websites - just remove the second field and move the button somewhere else. Here's an example:

```js
// This is our search input field.
const searchValue = document.getElementById('search_value');

// Here I'm looking for all search buttons and iterating over them
// with for ... of, querySelectorAll accepts valid CSS selectors.
for (let button of document.querySelectorAll('.search_button')) {
    // Getting the data-url attribute value from the button.
    const url = button.dataset.url;

    // Adding a click event handler, instead of relying on onclick=''
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Quick string replace...
        const targetURL = button.dataset.url.replace('%s', encodeURI(searchValue.value));
        // ...and here we open the new tab.
        window.open(targetURL, '_blank');
    });
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search_value" />
    <button class="search_button" data-url="https://nb.glosbe.com/en/nb/%s">Glosbe (en-no)</button>
    <button class="search_button" data-url="https://www.dict.com/engelsk-norsk/%s">Dict (en-no)</button>
</div>
```

Here's the explanation:

1. I'm using the HTML data-* attributes (accessible in JS via `element.dataset.*`) to store the URL, `%s` is being used as a placeholder for the search value and will be later replaced with the `.replace` function.
2. Instead of manually assigning IDs to buttons I've declared a class - this allows you to extend the application infinitely.
3. I've merged the input fields into just one and read its value in the button event handler.
4. I've replaced your `this.value=''` hack with a proper placeholder.
5. I've removed the table layout, if you wish to add a nicer layout or styling I would suggest to learn more about CSS - also: don't use HTML attributes to style elements (except for class and style). Avoid using ID selectors in CSS as well (it's fine in JS, but in CSS it can cause issues when it comes to importance). Also, you should avoid the style attribute anyway - it will take precedence over most CSS rules except for the rules with `!important` and causes code duplication.